# Integral convergence test for series $\frac{1}{n^p}*sin(\pi/3 *n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hey I have troubles with the following problem

I have to use the integral test for convergence for this series

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^p}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot n\right)$$

$p\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$

to show absolute convergence

my main problem is that I can't evaluate the integral for p=2

$$\mid\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}*x\right) |$$

I would be very grateful if anyone would like to help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't evaluate the integral, estimate it.

Comment: You want the absolutes inside the integral.  And you need to show that $|\sin(x)|\le1$

Comment: $\int_{1}^{\infty}\mid  \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot sin(\frac{\pi}{3} \cdot x)\mid$

Comment: It's stated in my book that $\mid sin(x) \mid \leq 1$ for all x. Can I then replace the sin with 1?

Comment: @Bateman You would say $$\int|\frac1{x^2}\sin(\frac\pi3\cdot x)|\le\int|\frac1{x^2}|$$

Comment: @Bateman Can you do it now?

Comment: Yeah I think hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

The integral test doesn't really apply, at least not its usual way. You are talking about $\sum_n |\sin (n\pi/3)|/n^p.$ But the terms of this series don't decrease with $n,$ so the hypotheses of the test aren't satisfied.

However: Let $c = (\sqrt 3)/2.$ Our series is

$$\frac{c}{1^p} + \frac{c}{2^p} + \frac{c}{4^p} + \frac{c}{5^p} + \cdots $$

That is a subseries of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c}{n^p}.$$

That one can be handled with the integral test.